# How to import specific data from API website

Tags: c#

I have an assignment to create a wpf app that collects data from API website. The data must be displayed in JSON format and I have to show only specific data like, email, first name and so on. I am showing the data in a TextBox and so far I have successfully made that all the API website info is shown. Here is the code so far:

```cs
   private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        private const string apiUrl = "https://reqres.in/api/users/3"; // Replace this with the API endpoint URL

        public DMCsearch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string searchTerm = searchBox.Text.Trim();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a search term.");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl + "?query=" + searchTerm);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // Here, you can process the jsonResponse as needed and display the data in the resultTextArea.
                    // For example, you can deserialize the JSON string and display specific information.

                    resultTextArea.Text = jsonResponse;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to retrieve data. Status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output. As I said I want to display specific values like `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`...

> {"data":
> {"id":3,"email":"emma.wong@reqres.in","first_name":"Emma","last_name":"Wong","avatar":"https‍://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"},"support":
> {"url":"https‍://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}